# IOTA not a blockchain but uses directed acylic graph (DAG) which is what ethereum ethhash is based on (dagger)

Tags: dag

IOTA claims that it is not a blockchain. IOTA uses directed acylic graph (DAG) which is what ethereum ethhash is based on in its early variant ([Dagger](http://www.hashcash.org/papers/dagger.html), an algorithm by Vitalik Buterin which uses directed acyclic graphs).

Can someone explain?

Answer (score 2):

A DAG is just a mathematical concept were you have directed edges and vertices, with the property that if you start from a vertice a follow the edges (in the correct direction): you cannot visit a vertice more than once.

When it comes to computer science: a DAG is a particular **data-structure** (understand "*data-structure*" as "*a way to organize information*") sharing the same properties as the mathematical-DAG. Usually the information is associated with vertices (but nothing prevent a developper to use a DAG with information associated to edges).

When it comes to the Tangle: a DAG-data-structure is at the heart of the system because this the data-structure in use to store transactions.

I'm not a Dagger expert, but as far as I understand, Dagger is a mining algorithm and this algorithm use a DAG internally. Dagger and it's DAG aren't use to organize transaction on the Ethereum network. So the use of the DAG-data-structure in Dagger is completely different that the usage of the DAG-data-structure in the Tangle.

Note that, strictly speaking, [the main data-structure in blockchains is also a DAG](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/1104/a-blockchain-is-a-specific-type-of-dag-true-or-false) (with just some additional constraints)